# Netbeans AutoComplete Methods Zend Model Classes

Tags: php, zend-framework, netbeans, autocomplete, zend-db-table

I have the following models classes however netbeans 7.0.1 autocomplete doesn't work for row classes.

Model Class:

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_Payments extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {
    protected $_name = 'payments';
    protected $_rowClass = 'Application_Model_Payment';

}
```

Row Class:

```
class Application_Model_Payment extends Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract {
    public function setIdentifier($identifier = null){
        return $this->identifier = $identifier;
    }
}
```

Code:

```
$paymentsModel = new Application_Model_DbTable_Payments();
$payment = $paymentsModel->find(1)->current();// return an Application_Model_Payment Object 
$payment->setIdentifier();//doesn't appear on netbeans autocomplete, only Zend_Db_Table_Row methods appers
```

How could I make netbeans show row class methods?

Comment: You don't have any class called Application_Model_DbTable_Payments, you have Application_Model_DbTable_Paymenty and Application_Model_Payment

Comment: Ops wrong typed, I just corrected it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because netbeans uses heavily the docblock comments (and in this case find is an inherited method), unless you explicitly put the return type in the comment block for a method, Netbeans hasn't really got a clue what to do.

You can give it a hand though by doing adding a block like this:

```
/* @var $variable ClassName */
```

like so in your code

```
$paymentsModel = new Application_Model_DbTable_Payments();

/* @var $payment Application_Model_Payment */
$payment = $paymentsModel->find(1)->current();// return an Application_Model_Payment Object 
$payment->setIdentifier();
```

It will 'hint' netbeans as to what the variable is.

UPDATE: Here is an example of doing it from the class/method declaration. In this example $something is instantiation of Application_Model_Token.

```
class User
{
  /**
   * @return Application_Model_Token
   */
  public function reset()
  {
    //Some code etc
    return $something
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to move this line into the method DocBloc if the class assignment takes place in a Class method? I'd prefer not to have to include these one line comments every where TBH

Comment: yep - just put the class declaration in your return for the method docblock (this does sort of fall apart slightly with Zend_Db as netbeans can't work out what the return will be sometimes as it can't know without running what class some object will be (e.g row classes)

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but can you explain what you mean with an example?

Comment: Thanks James but that's not really what I mean. I've posted my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9429874/253195 - instead of spamming this one :-)